# Bootstrap Image Gallery - last photo won't show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery

Trying to add the Bootstrap Image Gallery to one of the pages of this website I'm building. Followed instructions precisely - with the only exception that I am not remotely including some of the JS and CSS but uploaded everything on the local server.

For some reason I am unable to detect, the last photo will not show (upon pressing NEXT or PREVIOUS buttons), and this leaves the page stuck: the grey background is loaded but no photo and no controls. The only way out is to press ESC. And no image will load if the last image is clicked first.

Hope you can help me sort out this issue. Here's a link to the page: http://housemates.biz/view_new.php?property_id=6 . The problem occurs for every property ID, and it is always the last image that won't show.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. The `width` of the `<div class='slides'>` has a certain `width`. This `width` is too small, which results in the last image going under the second last image. I don't know how you have set your Javascript, but if you increase the `width` of that `div` it will work.

Comment: The `width` of `<div class="slides">` is not specifically set, it is calculated by JQuery and is supposed to be much larger than the viewport -- when I inspect it here, it shows 2560px. The `width` of `<div class="slide">` is also automatically calculated and in my case is 1280px (the width of my display).

I have just checked the CSS and I can't see any width setting in there.

Comment: I just looked at the `jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js` file and I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think there's something wrong with it, something like a missing - or an extra - quote somewhere because halfway through the code all the text goes pink (this is how EditPlus shows strings enclosed in double quotes)...